# Question regarding adiabatic process (Ex 12.2 in Blundell's Concepts in Thermal Physics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, differentiation, adiabatic

It can be derived from first law of thermodynamics that
$$dQ=\bigg(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\bigg)_V dT +\bigg[\bigg(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\bigg)_T+p\bigg]dV$$

On page 119 of the book, a question asks us to prove that $pV^\gamma$ is a constant from the following equation
$$dQ=\bigg(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial V}\bigg)_p dV + \bigg(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial p}\bigg)_V dp=0$$ for an adiabatic change.

I don't know how the second equation describing $dQ$ for adiabatic process came about and also have no idea how to prove that $pV^\gamma$ is a constant from that equation. Can anyone please enlighten me? Thank you.

The image attached below is a screenshot of the question (the book should be first edition published in 2006)
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is e.g. $\partial Q / \partial V$ in the second equation? Which edition of the book?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I added a screenshot of the question from the book in the question. The book was published in 2006, so should be the 1st edition

Comment: I don't really know how to understand the equation, to be honest. Heat is not a state function, so the derivative seems meaningless. However, for a reversible process, you could, I guess, use the relation to the entropy (which is a state function) and probably arrive at the equations 12.26-12.28 with some sort of 'abuse of notation' - but again, that is just a guess.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/489057/show-that-pv-gamma-is-a-constant-for-an-adiabatic-process?rq=1).

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. Since that equation is wrong to a certain extent, how would you correct it? @JasonFunderberker

Comment: Have you tried what I've described in the above comment? I don't know if this will lead to the result, but it could be worth a try. What I think, but again, I don't know, is that they derived an equation for $\mathrm dS$ and then used the relation for $\mathrm dS$ with $Q$ for a reversible process to rewrite the obtained equation in terms of $\delta Q$. Introducing e.g. $\partial Q /\partial V$ seems unnecessary (and not well-defined) to me. I can't stress enough: I am just guessing, I don't have the book and I've never seen some sort of derivation like this before... So I could be wrong.